# Why does my wifi fail to stay connected?

Tags: wireless-networking

We have 5 different laptops in the house, 1 macbook, 1 Compaq, 3 dells, plus numerous little devices like ipods, squeezeboxs, squeezebox radios and controllers, you name it.

All of them connect to and stay connected to the "downstairs" WIFI just fine.  But my laptop (the most expensive of the lot) refuses to stay connected, preferring the much weaker and slower signal upstairs.

My laptop is running Win7 (64 bit) Ultimate with an Intel 3945ABG WIFI contoller (It's a Dell Precision M6300).  The WIFI Access Point is a Cisco  WRT54G2 V1 with firmware:

```
Firmware: DD-WRT v24-sp2 (10/10/09) micro
Time: 11:11:10 up 42 min, load average: 0.06, 0.01, 0.00
WAN: Disabled
```

Comment: Try another radio channel in the router.

Comment: As part of writing this up, I determined the upstairs and downstairs wifi were both on Channel 1 (upstairs was set on auto).  I moved upstairs to channel 2 but that had no effect.  Nearby neighborhoods are on channel 6.

Comment: You could use NetStumbler to help determine interference

Comment: I used it on my XP machine and found most nearby networks to be on Channel 6.  My networks are are Channel 1 and 2 (2 being the one that is giving me connection issues).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've been unable to get it to accept a new firmware (Tomato, or the original Cisco/Linksys firmware).  I was able to change the power settings from 71mw to 251mw and that seems to have fixed my problem.

Answer (score 2):

If it persists, I recommend you upgrade the WRT54G2 V1 to the [Tomato Firmware by polarcloud.com](http://www.polarcloud.com/tomato). The firmware is far better at negotiating wireless issues. The  (edited) screen shot below shows wireless clients in my network with signal strength. I also provided a log screen and bandwidth. The firmware is much more configurable IMHO. [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index) is also pritty good from my understanding.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: So far I've been unable to get it to upgrade from DD-WRT to Tomato.  It just says "Upgrade Failed"  I'm using `WRT54G_WRT54GL.bin` to upgrade it without success.  Going to try going back to the cisco firmware and upgrading from there.